# how to use specific attributes that are declare in XML in CSS to design the website

Tags: html, css, xml, xml-parsing

here is my code of xml of the car shop website, and I want to add different image for each item attribute that are declared in xml in CSS. How do I access the attribute of xml to add the image from CSS.

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="catalog_18029952.css"  title="Test" media="screen"  type="text/css"?>


  <items>
  <item itemNum="1" itemType="Hatchback">
    <description>A hatchback car is a vehicle that has a large door in the back that swings upward, While many other models also use this type of door, a hatchback car is traditionally looked at as a small coupe- to sedan-size car with a raise-open door in the back instead of a trunk.</description>
    <quantity>7</quantity>
    <car type="used">
      <brandName>Maruti Swift</brandName>
      <manufacturer>Suzuki</manufacturer>
      <carInfo>Features on offer include auto LED projector headlamps with LED DRLs, tail lamps with LED brake lights, and a 7-inch touchscreen infotainment system with Apple CarPlay and Android Auto compatibility.it also gets rear parking sensors with parking camera.</carInfo>
      <carType>Fuel</carType>
      <color>Red</color>
      <price>$9,000</price>
      <previousOwner>Hardik Poudel</previousOwner>
    </car>
  </item> 

  <!--information about the second car-->
  <item itemNum="2" itemType="Luxury">
    <description>The term luxury is used to categorize vehicles that are equipped with better performance capabilities, lavish interiors and all the latest safety and technology features. In the past, cars such as BMW and Land Rover were known as the luxury vehicles.</description>
    <quantity>2</quantity>
    <car type="new">
      <brandName>Range Rover</brandName>
      <manufacturer>Land Rover</manufacturer>
      <carInfo>Land Rover’s most luxurious SUV, the Range Rover, is offered with four engine options in total - two petrol and two diesel.The diesel engine options are a 3.0-litre V6 unit making 258PS and a 4.4-litre V8 unit that churns out 340PS of power.</carInfo>
      <carType>Fuel</carType>
      <color>Blue</color>
      <price>$390,000</price>
      <interiorColor>Ivory leather</interiorColor>
    </car>
  </item>

  </items>
</vehicles>
```

Here I want to add different image of each of the item inside the XML, how do I use the particular attribute of the item so that it is selected.

Answer (score 0):

The tags are just..tags, so like any tag you can target them with their attributes in the css. Hope this is what you are looking for. But if you need more freedom in styling you could use a template to parse the XML in..

```css
item{
 background:#f00;
}

item[itemNum="1"]{
background:#00f;
}

item[itemNum="1"] color{
background:#fc0;
}
```

```html
<?xml-stylesheet href="catalog_18029952.css"  title="Test" media="screen"  type="text/css"?>


  <items>
  <item itemNum="1" itemType="Hatchback">
    <description>A hatchback car is a vehicle that has a large door in the back that swings upward, While many other models also use this type of door, a hatchback car is traditionally looked at as a small coupe- to sedan-size car with a raise-open door in the back instead of a trunk.</description>
    <quantity>7</quantity>
    <car type="used">
      <brandName>Maruti Swift</brandName>
      <manufacturer>Suzuki</manufacturer>
      <carInfo>Features on offer include auto LED projector headlamps with LED DRLs, tail lamps with LED brake lights, and a 7-inch touchscreen infotainment system with Apple CarPlay and Android Auto compatibility.it also gets rear parking sensors with parking camera.</carInfo>
      <carType>Fuel</carType>
      <color>Red</color>
      <price>$9,000</price>
      <previousOwner>Hardik Poudel</previousOwner>
    </car>
  </item> 

  <!--information about the second car-->
  <item itemNum="2" itemType="Luxury">
    <description>The term luxury is used to categorize vehicles that are equipped with better performance capabilities, lavish interiors and all the latest safety and technology features. In the past, cars such as BMW and Land Rover were known as the luxury vehicles.</description>
    <quantity>2</quantity>
    <car type="new">
      <brandName>Range Rover</brandName>
      <manufacturer>Land Rover</manufacturer>
      <carInfo>Land Rover’s most luxurious SUV, the Range Rover, is offered with four engine options in total - two petrol and two diesel.The diesel engine options are a 3.0-litre V6 unit making 258PS and a 4.4-litre V8 unit that churns out 340PS of power.</carInfo>
      <carType>Fuel</carType>
      <color>Blue</color>
      <price>$390,000</price>
      <interiorColor>Ivory leather</interiorColor>
    </car>
  </item>

  </items>
</vehicles>
```